# What ships can Marine Frigates capture in Homeworld 2?

Tags: homeworld-remastered-collection, homeworld-2

There is a remastered version of both Homeworld games and it seems like there have been some changes. If I remember correctly, very few enemy ship types could be captured using Marine Frigates in the original Homeworld 2. I'm now replaying the Remastered version and having trouble capturing a Vaygr Carrier in mission 3. Posts on the internet confirm this is not just me. Before I invest in Marine Frigates, which ships are known to be capturable, and which are not?

Answer (score 2):

In the HW2:RM (and original HW2) campaign, you can't capture enemy production units (carriers, facilities, motherships etc). Destroyers and hyperspace gates and I think resourcing units too are all fair game though. Also I don't think you can capture corvettes or smaller but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Finally, unlike HW1/HW1:RM, you can't capture units above your unit cap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in skirmish mode and you'll see.
The only ships you can't capture are the ships that are smaller than marine frigate, you can send marine frigate to capture the mothership but it wont actually capture it as you already have one, instead it will disable it.
 It is possible since I have already managed to capture a enemy shipyard in skirmish mode.

And for example if you play Hiigaran and you capture a Vaygr shipyard you can play the two races in the same game.

In addition to that i would say that capture a shipyard is more interesting than capture a mother-ship. Due to the fact that, in a shipyard you can produce every scale of unit from probes to battle cruiser. 
And in a mother-ship you can't produce battle cruiser .

And of course if you play Vaygr , with infiltrator frigate you can capture a Hiigaran shipyard.

The main difficulty in capturing enemy ship is the number of frigate you have to use to capture the enemy ships.
 The more the ship is big, the more you'll need marine frigate to even try to board the enemy ships.

for frigate you'll need one marine frigate

for destroyer i recommend three and more since a destroyer is a anti-frigate vessel. And due to that fact i do not recommend to try to capture destroyer.

Every production vessel is worthy to capture . 
If you can take shipyard you'll access the technologies, and the vessels of both races.

another point with marine frigate is that they generally are priority target for the enemy, and so they'll give you an advantage in terms of initiative in the fight.

**In conclusion** 
i would say that a transporter is really the best thing.For two reason,

-This a week ship and it is fast to capture it.

-If you spend enough money you 'll be able to call a shipyard and with the shipyard you'll be able to access every ships from the enemie race.

Comment: There's a problem with skirmish mode − it doesn't feature all the ships which you can meet throughout the campaign. I'm also interested in which of those ships are capturable.

Comment: i'll complete my answer later i'm at work